# TestNG - Can a dataprovider test method be ignored in the test execution report?

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I am using a dataProvider method and forming a URL using this dataprovider and should pass this formed URL to next dataprovider . Can this dataprovider Test Method be ignored in the TestNG - test execution reports?

The first DataProvider A should be ignored in the TestNG - test execution report

```java
@Test(dataprovider = "A")    
public void getURL(String URL){    
    finalURL = URL +apiURL;    
}

@Test(dataprovider ="B")    
public void getStatus(){    
    closeableHttpResponse = restClient.get(finalURL, headerFormation());     
}
```

Comment: Would love to see a small screenshot in your question, showing the problem.

Comment: please let me know if you need any specific details. The code which I am using is above . There are 2 tests - and I want to ignore one of the Test in reports

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way of doing this. A data driven test method is also a `@Test` method. TestNG doesn't distinguish them from a regular test method.

So the default reports within TestNG doesnot have this ability.

You can instead do the following:

1. Make sure you are using TestNG `7.0.0-beta1` (latest released version as of today)
2. Implement `org.testng.IReporter` (the reporting listener for testng).
3. For every `ITestResult` object, just check if its a data driven method (You can do that by inspecting `result.getMethod().isDataDriven()` and checking if its true)
4. If (3) is `false` you build a report for it and if (3) is `true` skip reporting the result for the test method.